# How do I use an old command that was changed in a package?

Tags: symbols, mathabx

After I finish mathematical proofs, I use `\square`. Recently, I added a new package called `mathabx` into my document. This package changes the look of `\square` (makes the square smaller, and this is shown in its documentation). How do I still use the package (for other purposes) yet keep the old `\square`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\square` isn't defined by the LaTeX kernel, so please make a small compilable example that shows the `\square` you want, and that changes when `mathabx` is loaded.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. The `mathabx` package changes lots of characters so it may not be only `\square` that is changed.  Possibly [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386) is a duplicate.

Comment: Why not use `\qed`, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910493/qed-symbol-in-latex

Comment: Save it before loading the package that changes it. `\let\mysquare\square`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is mentioned above, you can include the package like so

```
\let\mysquare\square % preserve old \square command
\usepackage{mathabx}
```

and then use `\mysquare` instead of square.

Comment: This works well! Thanks so much and sorry for the late feedback.